# segmentation fault in malloc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have a written the following program and every time I try to run it I get a segmentation fault. I think the problem is at the malloc of the array subsets on line 149. I tried to debug it with gdb but it says that there is a problem in function find which doesn't make any sense at all. If somebody ever had a similar problem plz help. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

long int N;

// a structure to represent a weighted edge in graph
struct Edge
{
    long int src, dest ;
    long int weight;
 };

 // a structure to represent a connected, undirected and weighted graph
 struct Graph
 {
 struct Edge* edge;
  };


  // A structure to represent a subset for union-find
  struct subset
  {
        long int parent;
        long int rank;
        long long int vertex;
   };


    // A utility function to find set of an element i
    long int find(struct subset subsets[], long int i)
    {
        // find the root and make root as parent of i (path compression)
       if (subsets[i].parent != i)
       subsets[i].parent = find(subsets, subsets[i].parent);

       return subsets[i].parent;
     } 


     // Union of two sets of x and y
     // (uses union by rank)
     void Union(struct subset subsets[],long int x,long int y)
     {
        long int xroot = find(subsets, x);
        long int yroot = find(subsets, y);
            // Attach smaller rank tree under root of high rank tree
        // (Union by Rank)
        if (subsets[xroot].rank < subsets[yroot].rank){
             subsets[xroot].parent = yroot;
             subsets[yroot].vertex += subsets[xroot].vertex;
        }
        else if (subsets[xroot].rank > subsets[yroot].rank){
             subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
             subsets[xroot].vertex += subsets[yroot].vertex;
        }
        // If ranks are same, then make one as root and increment
        // its rank by one
        else
        {
        subsets[yroot].parent = xroot;
        subsets[xroot].rank++;
            subsets[xroot].vertex += subsets[yroot].vertex;
        }
       }

     // Compare two edges according to their weights.
     // Used in qsort() for sorting an array of edges
     int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
     {
        struct Edge* a1 = (struct Edge*)a;
        struct Edge* b1 = (struct Edge*)b;
        return (a1->weight - b1->weight);
      }




      int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
        int j;
        long int i;
        long int n1, n2, w;
        long long int sum=0;
        FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

        if (!f) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        fscanf(f, "%ld", &N);

        struct Graph* graph = (struct Graph*) malloc( sizeof(struct Graph) );

        graph->edge = (struct Edge*) malloc( N * sizeof( struct Edge ) );
        for (i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
            fscanf(f, "%ld", &n1);
            fscanf(f, "%ld", &n2);
            fscanf(f, "%ld", &w);

            graph->edge[i].src = n1;
            graph->edge[i].dest = n2;
            graph->edge[i].weight = w;
        }

        long int x,y;
        struct Edge next_edge ;

        qsort(graph->edge, N-1, sizeof(graph->edge[0]), comp);

            /*
        for (i = 0; i < N -1 ; i++)
        {
            printf("%ld\t %ld\t %ld\n", graph->edge[i].src, graph->edge[i].dest,             graph->edge[i].weight); 
        }
         */
        // Allocate memory for creating V subsets
        struct subset *subsets = (struct subset*) malloc( N * sizeof(struct subset) );
        // Create V subsets with single elements
        for (j = 0 ; j < N ; j++)
        {
                subsets[j].parent = 0;
            subsets[j].rank = 0;
            subsets[j].vertex = 1 ; 
        }

        i = 0; 
        while (i < N-1)
        {
            next_edge = graph->edge[i--];
            x = find(subsets, next_edge.src);
            y = find(subsets, next_edge.dest);
            if (x != y){
                      sum += graph->edge[i].weight + ( ( graph->edge[i].weight +1 ) * (subsets[x].vertex*subsets[y].vertex-1));
                Union(subsets, x, y);
            }
        }

        printf("%lld\n", sum);

        return 0 ;
       }
```

P.S. The purpose of the program is, given an MST, to calculate the weight of a full tree in a way that the given MST is its only MST.

Comment: Can you please narrow the code down to the troublesome parts? You can do it by running the program in a debugger, it will stop when the crash happen and let you examine the call stack (at least please include that in your question) and even walk up the call stack where it will let you examine values of variables. Since you mention segmentation faults, you may want to read about [the GNU Debugger and read its online manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/)

Answer (score 2):

The probable cause it his loop:

```
i = 0; 
while (i < N-1)
{
    next_edge = graph->edge[i--];
    ...
}
```

Here you start out with index zero, then *decrease it*. So when you use `i` as index later in the loop it will have the value `-1` and you will index out of bounds for the allocated memory, leading to *undefined behavior*. The loop itself may also run for as long as `i` is negative, until it underflows to become the max signed `long` value (so you will loop over two billion times).

Comment: you are so right. it was a careless mistake but generally the problem was this. plus i should do this initialisation "next_edge = graph->edge[i--]" by fields. now the program is not completely correct, but at least it runs! thnx!